# How to textbox readonly that are associated with usercontrol?

Tags: c#, asp.net

In multiple textboxes that are associated with usercontrol but i want to readonly one of them e.g srhreagion but it is not working

```
 <tr>
    <td style="width: 33%;">
      <SearchList:Search ID="SrhRegion" runat="server" LookupType="Region" Readonly="true"/>
    </td>
    <td style="width: 33%;">
      <SearchList:Search ID="SrhSalesOffice" runat="server" LookupType="Sales_Office" />
    </td>
    <td style="width: 33%;">
      <SearchList:Search ID="SrhSPN" runat="server" LookupType="Sales_Group" />
    </td>
  </tr>
```

Comment: what not working exactly?

Comment: "SrhRegion" i want to readonly that textbox so the user not type in it although readonly is true but not working

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean - you want to set one of the textboxes *inside* the usercontrol to read-only ? Or do you mean - you want to set one of the `<SearchList:Search>` usercontrols to read-only ?

If it's the textbox that should simply be a case of setting its readonly property to True: -

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtBox" runat="server" ReadOnly="true" />
```

(Or do this in code, depending on your scenario)

If it's the usercontrol, you will need to implement your own "ReadOnly" property on the usercontrol itself, and when someone changes its value, you set the ReadOnly property of the control or controls you want.

For example: -

```
public bool ReadOnly
{
    get
    {
        return txtBox.ReadOnly;
    }
    set
    {
        txtBox.ReadOnly = value;
        someOtherControl.ReadOnly = value;
        anotherControl.ReadOnly = value;
    }
}
```

Hope that helps

Comment: You put that property in your usercontrol, and changed the names to fit your control names ? Can you show me a) your usercontrol code and b) your call to it; the above sample code is from working production code, with the names edited.